# why i cant see change in ifg port in msp430

Tags: embedded, interrupt, msp430, iar

I cant see any change in the P2IFG register also not on live watch while clicking the on the right flag on forced interrupt.

I checked the config and I think they are set good.

Here is the screenshot of the IAR software while I'm debugging

[image]

Comment: 1/ could you try P2IE, P2IES and P2IFG set to 0x0F?

Comment: 2/ could you try without sleep mode? (in LPM4: #GIE,SR) ?